# Google Sheets: How to Use Importrange and concat with QUERY

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import data from a Google Sheet with Importrange.

To get the info from 3 columns and according to the value of a cel (B2, where I put the names), I use concatenate.
But even if it works, when I have a value with `@` (like a user `@name` it gets nothing) or I have more than 2 values for one person, it doesn't work.

Any idea of what to do?

We have to put `;` instead of `,` because it's in Spanish.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxxxxx";"CRM!A:F");CONCATENATE("SELECT Col4 WHERE Col2='";B2;"'");0)
```

Answer (score 0):

run first this to connect sheets:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxxxxx"; "CRM!A1")
```

then try:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxxxxx"; "CRM!A:F")}; 
 "select Col4 where Col2='"&B2&"'"); 0)
```

if B2 is numeric number use:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxxxxx"; "CRM!A:F")}; 
 "select Col4 where Col2="&B2); 0)
```

if B2 has multiple names or one name only try:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxxxxx"; "CRM!A:F")}; 
 "select Col4 where Col2 matches '"&B2&"'"); 0)
```

but B2 needs to be written as

```
name1|name2
```

eg. separated with `|`

also note that names needs to be exact and the whole thing is case sensitive

to combat case sensitivity you can change

```
where Col2 matches '"&B2&
```

to

```
where lower(Col2) matches '"&LOWER(B2)&
```

and if you want to run partial names from B2 then B2 needs to look like:

```
.*name1.*|.*name2.*
```

Comment: Thank you so much @player0 for your detailed explanation.

I tried your code and it works as using concatenate, with one exception, that the last  digit (0) works the same with 0 and with 1, I mean, it shows the header anyway.

It's interesting that the {} let us use &, but as I have text on those cells, I don't know if makes any difference.

So, right now, if I select one user that has several lines with text, it just works if those lines have the same text. If they have different text, it doesn't show anything.

Can I add images to explain it better?
Now I add the 2 codes that work!

Comment: =SI.ERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/.....";"....!A:J");CONCATENAR("SELECT Col3, Col5, Col6  WHERE Col2='";B8;"'");0);"")

Comment: And this is the other with your format, that works everything but the last digit, that it does not let me take out the header...

Comment: =SI.ERROR(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/......";"....!A:J")};"SELECT Col3 WHERE Col2 matches '"&B8&"'");1)

Comment: Oh, I found the error... It was that 3 users wrote their emails with an space at the end, so it was not finding them!!! I was using the email as Primary Key, and 2 of them where the one that had several registrations.... 

Thank you so much @player0, I learned a lot with your indications. Let's see if I can go further!!! Regards